# Caching PHP - MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I created a basic php page which is querying a MySQL DB (MyISAM) - read only. It has a table with 7fields and ~6 million records.

Something like :

> ID | Category | Name | Price | Date ...

Running a basic select query on this table takes like 4-5ms.

```
Select * from mytable where ID = 'myID'.
```

I've already set it up the caching, so if I run the same select again it's instant.

Is there any easy way to cache all the select queries automatically? (Generate all the selects and run them after server restart, or something like that.)

Like I said its a read-only db, so the solution doesn't need to be dynamic.

Thank you.

Comment: 6M rows in MyISAM... ouch. No way to convert to InnoDB?

Comment: If there isn't anything dynamic, you can just cache the output html

Comment: Do you really need to present all the results in a single page?

Comment: I can convert the DB to InnoDB, but someone suggested the MyISAM engine perform better with "read-only" tables.

I don't need to present all the data on one page, only what is belongs to the ID. (Normally between 10-50 records.)